# Rewriting a NodeJS Website using Oracle APEX

Tags: node.js, ejs, oracle-apex

My company is upgrading our database hardware to facilitate a data process that potentially may not work (... long story) and in order to somewhat justify the purchase in case the data process does not work, the idea has been floated around of rewriting the site using Oracle APEX. I am wondering about the limitations of APEX and have been unable to find a solution to a few questions.

I currently have a fairly complex, dynamic ecommerce website written in NodeJS and ExpressJS using EJS for templating. There is a lot of logic done inside the .ejs files and the partial templates themselves are re-used in various places throughout the site. We are using ORDS calls from the Node server to retreive data from the database.

I am mainly curious about how one would go about implementing something similar to EJS partial views in APEX. I am pretty new to APEX (2-3 months working on another application) so I haven't gotten too in depth into the way templates are used, past the normal #REGION_01# substitution of simple elements.

I am assuming that most of the logic (deciding whether to show element A or element B based on a value from the database record of the product) would be done in PL/SQL or in a separate JS file.

Is something like the following possible?

1. A template containing a "Add To Cart" Button, MSRP, Sale Price, and a (HTML) table displaying possible discounts based on the quantity purchased
2. A template containing product information, like the product ID, name, manufacturer, and a small description of the product
3. A template combining the previous 2 options and a picture of the product into a row that can be re-used across the site

If someone has experience with this sort of thing, or could point me towards some good reference material on a similar topic, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure I'll be able to answer this succinctly here.  I work in product development for Oracle APEX.  If you mention me on Twitter (@joelkallman), I can try and connect with you and I'd be happy to discuss this with you in Zoom, just to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with Oracle APEX for a while, specially in the front-end department because it does lack a bit in regards templates.

To answer your question. It depends on what you mean by template

**If templates are the apex template objects**

You can create and customize templates on Shared Components -> Templates. I'm almost sure you need to create new stuff or duplicate because the vanilla ones are locked.

Another option is to create plugins for you app which will function similarly and can be exported/shared with other projects and people.

**If Template is just a page that you will keep changing the record displayed**

Sure, you can create many things using the a blank page and adding the components. I've on teams developing ERPs, Mobile Apps, Stock Integration with Marketplaces (needed some Java, though) and several custom made Application that are not available out-of-the-box.